# Vectorization of 2 for loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have just started exploring world of vectorization.  I got the 1-D vectorization down but i am having trouble vectorizing the following code. I want to do away with at least one of the for loops if possible b/c I plan to use this on a much larger data set over many iterations so saving computation time is of the essence.

```
CityPairs = [7 3
3 1
3 1
1 7
7 1
3 4
5 1
4 6];
Offices = [1;3;7];
nOffices = size(Offices,1);

connection = zeros(nOffices);
for i = 1:nOffices
    for j = 1:nOffices
        connection(i,j) = sum(Offices(i) == CityPairs(:,1)...
            & CityPairs(:,2) == Offices(j));
    end
end   
disp(connection)
```

In this example there are 7 cities, three of which have offices.  I want a pairwise matrix for the cities with offices to capture the sum of all the one way connections between each.  The answer for above problem should be:

```
 0     0     1
 2     0     0
 1     1     0
```

Any suggestions are welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Keith

Comment: Any reason for `connection(i,:) = connection(i,:);`? Otherwise remove the line.

Comment: it was part of something else I did, unimportant here - i have removed it.

Comment: So you want another answer or is your problem solved?

Comment: problem solved.  i just couldn't post my own answer until after 6 hours.  thanks for the alternative solutions - i will check them out later and give credit for ones that work appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution with `sparse`:

```
dims = max(max(CityPairs), max(Offices));
A = sparse(CityPairs(:, 1), CityPairs(:, 2), 1, dims(1), dims(2));
result = full(A(Offices, Offices));
```

This should speed up your computation a bit<sup>1</sup> when compared to the suggested `bsxfun` solution.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Runs 5 times faster on MATLAB 2012a (Windows Server 2008 R2 running on a 2.27GHz 16-core Intel Xeon processor)</sup>

Comment: Nice one, I always forget about sparse accumulation.

Comment: Eitan,I like this.  works fast, but I ran into a problem.  My data set changes dynamically and I have run into the situation where one of the columns of city pairs no longer has city indices greater that the largest office index which breaks the full operation.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Above I meant to say values and not indices.

Comment: @user2913719 Can you provide an example? I can't see how it breaks the operation.

Comment: ok, on small example i provided it doesn't (should have checked that first), but on larger sample set of 20K+ it is, but it my be something else is going on too.  Let e investigate more, in the mean time I'll hook you up on feedback!

Comment: Eitan, Finally found time to sit down with this (and change my userID).  In original example if you change Offices to [1,3,8] it will break because index exceeds dimensions - which I can understand why in my head, but not sure how to adjust for it in your solution.  The number of offices is fixed in my larger application, but the city pair connections change dynamically, inevitably shrinking to a size causing this error.  Any thoughts?  I see potential for using sparse throughout the rest of my code so getting to bottom of this would be of great help.  Thanks.  KD

Comment: @KeithD I think I got it. You get the error because matrix `A` has dimensions corresponding to the largest values in `CityPairs` (7 in your example), while you try to use subscripts with a greater value (that is 8). The remedy would be creating a sparse matrix with dimensions that correspond to the largest of the two. Please try my revised solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your task is some selective cross-tabulation. You can accomplish this easily by accumulating counts to the positions of interest, indexed by your `Offices`:

```
% Row and col subs
[~,rsubs] = ismember(CityPairs(:,1),Offices);
[~,csubs] = ismember(CityPairs(:,2),Offices);

% Select where both belong to Offices, i.e. non 0
subs = [rsubs,csubs];
subs = subs(all(subs,2),:);

% Accumulate
accumarray(subs,1)
```

The result

```
ans =
     0     0     1
     2     0     0
     1     1     0
```

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, you could use `crosstab` directly, but then you would need to select the rows and columns of interest:

```
crosstab(CityPairs(:,1),CityPairs(:,2))
ans =
     0     0     0     0     1
     2     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Actually, you can directly feed `accumarray` with the `CityPairs` and then select the rows and columns matching `Offices`, that is: `A = accumarray(CityPairs, 1); result = A(Offices, Offices);`...  (making this somewhat similar to my solution with `sparse`).

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Cedric Wannaz on MathWorks Forum

It is not trivial to "vectorize" this setup, as there are operations that require some look up table, and there is accumulation (unless you find a trick). This is likely to make the approach without FOR loops more complicated (code-wise) than the basic, loop-based approach. So let's start with the trick first ;-) ..

```
 A = double( bsxfun(@eq, CityPairs(:,1), Offices.') ) ;
 B = double( bsxfun(@eq, CityPairs(:,2), Offices.') ) ;
 A.' * B
```

Alternate approach: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91294-vectorization-of-2-for-loops-in-matlab